Using vscode's cmake plug-in, .asm files and .S files cannot be loaded
I'm encountering an issue while using the CMake plugin in VSCode. It seems unable to load .asm and .S files. I've tried several approaches, including configuring CMAKE_ASM_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS in settings.json and adding commands to CMakeLists.txt, but the problem persists.
Approaches I've Tried:
Added the following configuration to settings.json:
"cmake.configureSettings": {
    "CMAKE_ASM_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS": [
        ".asm",
        ".S"
    ]
}

Also, added the following lines to CMakeLists.txt:
ENABLE_LANGUAGE(ASM)
set_source_files_properties(${ASM_SOURCES} PROPERTIES LANGUAGE ASM)
set_source_files_properties(${ASM_SOURCES} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-x assembler-with-cpp")

I can't load .asm and .S files in VSCode using the CMake plugin. Despite trying the above solutions, the issue persists.

... what do you mean by "load"?
